# Convert binary unsigned vector to dec list

Tags: c

This code converts an `unsigned long` vector variable `cR1` to `NB_ERRORS` numbers (in `a` variable I print these numbers).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int EXT_DEGREE = 8;
int NB_ERRORS = 8;
int BIT_SIZE_OF_LONG = 32;
typedef unsigned short gf_t;
int main(void){

int j, k, l;
gf_t a;
unsigned long cR1 [] = {418636844,2037720909}; //example
for (l = 0; l < NB_ERRORS; ++l) {
    k = (l * EXT_DEGREE) / BIT_SIZE_OF_LONG;
    j = (l * EXT_DEGREE) % BIT_SIZE_OF_LONG;
    a = cR1[k] >> j;
    if(j + EXT_DEGREE > BIT_SIZE_OF_LONG)
        a ^= cR1[k + 1] << (BIT_SIZE_OF_LONG - j);
    a &= ((1 << EXT_DEGREE) - 1);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

For example I have a cR1 array with two elements that follow:

`0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0`
`1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0`

Executing that code I get:

```
    a = 44
    a = 228
    a = 243
    a = 24
    a = 77
    a = 39
    a = 117
    a = 121
```

This code convert from right to left, I want modify to convert from left to right. Where I will be able to modify this?

Comment: `This code convert from right to left, I want modify to convert from right to left` Great news! You don't have to change anything!

Comment: @AdrianCornish is very difficult provide a shorter example, this example is the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify `j` calculation line. Replace it by:

```
j = ( (NB_ERRORS - 1 - l) * EXT_DEGREE) % BIT_SIZE_OF_LONG;
```

The numbers contained in `cR1` will be converted starting from the left. The output will be:

```
a = 24
a = 243
a = 228
a = 44
a = 121
a = 117
a = 39
a = 77
```